# How to get to know that device is not moving in androig using GPS coordinates

Tags: android, gps

I want to stop locationlistener when device stops moving, for that i have written the function to calculate  the speed of the device,from that i can come to know that device is not moving if speed is zero, but i don't know where to call that function which calculates speed, suppose if i call it in onLocationChanged() then this function will call only whenever location updated, but i want call this function when location is not changing?

```
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

       time= time1;
       lat1=latitude;  //copy previous latitude value
       lng1=longitude;   //copy previous longitude value
       lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
       lng = Double.toString (location.getLongitude());
       time1 = location.getTime();
       latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
       longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
       latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat);
       longitude = Double.parseDouble(lng);
            dist=CalculateSpeed(latitude,longitude,lat1,lng1);
       speed=dist/(time1-time);
       text.setText(String.valueOf(speed)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Start using the new google play location services. You will find it much easier to use and much more accurate. The `LocationRequest` class has a method called `setSmallestDisplacement` which sets the minimum displacement between location updates. I have a full working sample here:

https://github.com/nickfox/GpsTracker/tree/master/phoneClients/android

Look at GpsTrackerActivity.java and after line 92 add the following:

```
locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10); // in meters
```

This says don't do a location update until we have moved 10 meters. Experiment with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method getLastKnownLocation() of the LocationManager class.You can compare the data obtained from this method at different intervals, if the result is same everytime then it means that your device is not moving.This method retrieves the last known location of the device, you can google more about it.Good luck

Comment: @nigtmare ya, but i am not getting how to use getLastKnownLocation() here?

Comment: Let that you just want to know that the device is stationary or mobile, then you can create an application with a background service in which you call your getLastKnownLocation () method, and with the use of AlarmManager, can adjust the timings that after how many intervals the service run again and get the last known location. Write the output of the method to a file and read it again whenever the service is run again.Compare them and you will get the difference. Try to split your work and then assemble the components.